# Batch file or Powershell: How to Kill all Process from a particular user

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, process, server

I wonder how you can write a batch file or powershell script that, given an input of a user name, that it goes and kill every processes that is owned by that user.

For example, if I input user name: testuser. I want the script to go and kill every system processes that its owner is testuser.

On a Windows Server 2008, 2012.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the command taskkill on windows server, you can kill any processes owned by specific user.

TASKKILL /F /FI "USERNAME eq "

Answer (score 0):

Using `powershell` you can list all processes started by a specified user:

```
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | where {$_.UserName -eq "<Username here>"}
```

To kill/stop a process, either call `.kill()` on each result or feed the result into `Stop-Process`.

Comment: Worth noting that the `-IncludeUserName` switch requires elevated permissions.